# How do I stop nHibernate to save on a view?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, view

I have a view that lists the cities and I have a table that saves the code of the city per individual. Now the field on the individual table CAN be null, but when I tried to do this it tries to insert into the view and it throws the following exception.

object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: iProduct.City, Entity: iProduct.City

If I try to set the mappings on the CaseIndividualMap to .Not.Insert or Not.Update then it ignores it and stores null but if it has a value it gets ignored as well.

Any ideas on how to map this correctly would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class CityMap : ClassMap<City>
{        
    public CityMap() {
        Table("vCities");
        ReadOnly();
        LazyLoad();

        Id(x => x.Code).Column("Code");
        Map(x => x.Description).Column("Description");
        Map(x => x.StateCode).Column("StateCode");
    }
}

public class CaseIndividualMap : StagingBaseMap<CaseIndividual>
{
    public CaseIndividualMap()
    {
        Table("CaseIndividuals");

        Map(x => x.CaseId);

        References(x => x.City)
            .Column("CityCode")
            .Cascade.None()
            .Nullable();                            
    }
}
```

BLL

```
public void AddIndividual(CaseIndividual individual, AuthenticatedUser user)
{            
    using (var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
    {                                
        _session.Save(individual);                
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the cities before setting the property of CaseIndividual?  You should only get that error message if the current NHibernate session isn't already aware of the city being referenced.

Comment: This is a save response to our business layer.  They pass a CaseIndividual with the objects already filled out.  The form shows a list of the cities and if it passes a value that matches the mapping on the city view it works and saves the individual.  If they don't select a city then it passes null, which is ok on our table for individuals, but it fails with that error "unsaved transient instance" posted above.

Comment: You might want to try loading that code in the debugger, and make sure that when the CaseIndividual is passed in, that the City property is actually null and not a new City object that's been created.

Comment: You where correct the City object was instantiated with null values.  I assumed that since the values where null nHibernate would ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception thrown and the story described do not match together. Because the exception:

> object references an unsaved transient instance ...
>   ... Type: **iProduct.City**, Entity: iProduct.City

Says: There **is** a **new** instance of the City, referenced by `CaseIndividual`, when the

```
...
_session.Save(individual);                
transaction.Commit();
```

is called. Other words, to get this type of exception the code had to look like this:

```
var city = new City(); // or other way how to get reference (not null)
...
individual.City = city;
```

What does it mean? If we do not want to assign the existing City *(already persisted, the one returned by the mapped `view`)* - The code must look like this:

```
...
individual.City = null; // here we go
_session.Save(individual);                
transaction.Commit();
```

And the above code snippet, will never throw "..unsaved transient instance..." exception, because there is none passed to session. There is no need for a special Mapping of the `CaseIndividualMap`, but...

#### Unsaved-value and City mapping

The `Id` of the entity `City` is mapped as *Code*. I guess, it is not of `int` type. It would be a `string`/`varchar`.

Now, NHibernate must now, if the incoming instance of a `City` is already persisted or if it is representing "new" *(transient)* instance. To make it easier and explicit, we have to extend the "id" mapping of a `City`:

public CityMap() 
   {
       Table("vCities");
       ...
       Id(x => x.Code)
          .Column("Code")
          .GeneratedBy.Assigned() // NHibernate expects that ID is managed by us
          .UnsavedValue("verydummyvalue or even null")

*Read here more about defaults of the unsaved-value: [9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached)*

The trick above, the **assinged** id and/or **unsaved-value** are correctly instructing NHibernate:

> When individual is coming, with assigned City.. which id (i.e.: code) differentiate from `unsaved-value`... do expect it is not transient - do not try to INSERT it

Comment: Ok I did that and it worked.  There was a City object but the properties where null.  For some reason I expected it to work with those conditions.  Thanks for the help and explanation.

Comment: Great to see that. Enjoy NHibernate ;)